# Laravel Fullcalendar implementation - issue: use moment().utcOffset instead

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

As the title says, im having trouble discovering how to fix that issue:

> "Deprecation warning: moment().zone is deprecated, use
>   moment().utcOffset instead.
>   https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1779"

I have read the issues on that link but i really don´t know how to implement things because the only thing I'm doing with moment is to declare the CDN on my blade file.

I have made this following [this](https://medium.com/@krissanawat/how-to-implement-jquery-fullcalendar-in-laravel-5-5-554d3deeb7c6) and [this](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar) mostly but i have also saw another tutorials...the calendar is showing but the error doesn´t disapear and **i also don´t know if this is related with another issue i have which is: the calendar is not accepting locale/translation definitions**

What am i missing here? thanks for your time, regards

Comment: It's only a warning, so for the time being you can choose to ignore it. The code mentioned is deprecated, not removed. The warning is to tell you it might be removed in future. Probably whatever JS code Laravel is injecting is a bit out of date - maybe an old fullCalendar and momentJS combination, or maybe they just haven't updated their code to deal with the deprecation. I can't tell you that since you haven't provided any code, or a link to whatever Laravel package you are using

Comment: As to why you can't use translations...are you aware you have to include an extra file for that? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale . Again it's unclear whether your page is using that or not, because you haven't provided any code or other information.

Comment: Hi ADyson, yes i should have provided code, but the solution for the warning to disapear was to do this in my controller: 'timezone' => 'UTC'...and the warning disapear...now, related with the translation i´m using this CDN on my blade file after the initiation of fullcallendar: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.0/lang-all.js"></script>

Comment: " 'timezone' => 'UTC'." makes the warning disappear because it means fullCalendar doesn't have to worry about translating the event data from one timezone to another. Instead everything is handled in the UTC zone. It doesn't mean the code is suddenly ok. If you changed the timezone setting to meet some requirement, it would come back.

Comment: Anyway since (from your CDN link) it appears you must be using an old version of fullCalendar (2.7 is very out of date now, 3.10 is the latest), the documentation I linked you to is wrong. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/lang would be the setting you'd need to set. It became "locale" instead from version 3.0 onwards.

Comment: (Of course if you're actually using a newer version of fullCalendar, then you need to make sure you get your locale / language files from the correct CDN location for that version instead).

Comment: And that´s what i was using, but the fullcalendar i´m using is 2.2.7 version, so in the options it was not: locale => pt but instead lang => pt.....and now it´s working, thanks for your suggestions ADyson, regards

Comment: wait...so you are saying that i should use the 3.0 version, do you know if there are significant differences?

Comment: The documentation pages link you to [this page](https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2016/09/feature-packed-releases) when you view the V2 docs. This explains what they changes are between v2 and v3. There are a few breaking changes but nothing significant, apart from the lang/locale stuff which is the subject of your question.

Comment: P.S. Actually I would suggest you use the latest 3.10 rather than 3.0

Comment: Done!!!...and working, thanks ADyson, regards.